# How to reproduce JSF web.xml vulnerability

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, glassfish-3

There is a known web.xml vulnerability exist in javax.faces 2.1 jar.
Please consider below URL to reproduce this issue and that was given by client side to reproduce this issue.

```
https://example.com/javax.faces.resource.../WEB-INF/web.xml.jsf (dummy URL)
```

but we are unable to reproduce this issue at our end.
We tried using below URLs to reproduce this issue at our end.

```
https://<external IP>:8181/javax.faces.resource.../WEB-INF/web.xml.jsf
https://<Localhost>:8181/javax.faces.resource.../WEB-INF/web.xml.jsf
https://<Localhost>:8181/ABC/javax.faces.resource.../WEB-INF/web.xml.jsf
```

Please note that deployed application structure are same at both ends.

So please any early help  to reproduce this issue would be highly appreciated as this issue high priority issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This is a very common issue with javax.faces 2.1 jar which is faced by various web applications.
But reproduction steps are not found clearly on following 1) upto how much depth would be achieved by putting how many ../../ should be put in URLfor  path traversal 2) sometimes not reproducible via local host or ip(intranet) why? is Java faces see any difference here?
Above points are very critical from the understanding. if some body can take time and explain would be helpful.